# Set up HTTPS on localhost for macOS [mac os catalina 10.15.2]

Tags: https, localhost

```
cd ~/
mkdir .localhost-ssl

sudo openssl genrsa -out ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.key 2048

sudo openssl req -new -x509 -key ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.key -out ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.crt -days 3650 -subj /CN=localhost

sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.crt

npm install -g http-server
echo " 
function https-server() {
  http-server --ssl --cert ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.crt --key ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.key
}
" >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

echo "You're ready to use https on localhost "
echo "Navigate to a project directory and run:"
echo ""
echo "https-server"
```

it's not working ...is there anything wrong with this code?

code source: https://gist.github.com/jonsamp/587b78b7698be7c7fd570164a586e6b7

Comment: It would be nice to add more related tags to your question like `shell`, `bash`, `ssl`, `ssl-certificate`, `npm` etc., better format your code sections, show the errors & logs you got instead of saying "its not working".

Comment: Thanks for response. actually there's no error.after all those terminal thing done and mentioned above, its supposed to show "Connection is secured" in my localhost.but its still showing "Your connection to this site is not secure". am I missing something here ?i followed this procedure :- https://medium.com/@jonsamp/how-to-set-up-https-on-localhost-for-macos-b597bcf935ee
@endo64

Answer (score 5):

After a few days of struggling I finally found a way to run **localhost** with **https**. I guess this solution will work on any macOS version.

from: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

I found this **minica** tool which is a simple CA intended for use in situations where the CA operator also operates each host where a certificate will be used. It automatically generates both a key and a certificate when asked to produce a certificate. It does not offer OCSP or CRL services. Minica is appropriate, for instance, for generating certificates for RPC systems or microservices.

https://github.com/jsha/minica

Step 1

```
brew install minica
```

Step 2

```
minica --domains localhost
```

> Generate a root key and cert in minica-key.pem, and minica.pem, then
> generate and sign an end-entity key and cert, storing them in
> ./localhost/
> [image]

Step 3

> add those cert and key files into your config server file. For example configure in: /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/WORK/www/webapp"
    ServerName localhost

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /Users/xxxx/selfsigned-certs/localhost/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /Users/xxxx/selfsigned-certs/localhost/key.pem

    <Directory "/Volumes/WORK/www/webapp">
        Options All
        MultiviewsMatch Any
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Step 4

> Restart server

Step 5

> in Keychain Access ---> File ---> Import Items
> import "minica.pem" file
>
> [image]

Step 6

> in Chrome browser when accessing the https://localhost you will get a message with a not trusted certificate
> to make it a trusted you must go to:
> **chrome://settings/security** --> "Manage certificates"
> from there open the "minica..." certificate and set it as trusted
>
> [image]

Step 7

> reopen https://localhost ---> it will recognise certificate as valid and trusted one
> [image]
>
> [image]

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to follow up on [Christi Maris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163560/cristi-maris)'s answer by suggesting `mkcert` https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert. It serves essentially the same purpose as `minica` but handles adding the certificates to the system trust store (and, optionally, the Firefox trust store) automatically.

From the `mkcert` documentation:

> mkcert is a simple tool for making locally-trusted development certificates. It requires no configuration.
>
> On macOS, use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
>
> ```
> brew install mkcert
> brew install nss # if you use Firefox
> ```

`mkcert` is also available for [Linux](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert?tab=readme-ov-file#linux) and [Windows](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert?tab=readme-ov-file#windows)

> ```
> $ mkcert -install
> Created a new local CA 
> The local CA is now installed in the system trust store! ⚡️
> The local CA is now installed in the Firefox trust store (requires browser restart)! 
>
> $ mkcert example.com "*.example.com" example.test localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
>
> Created a new certificate valid for the following names 
> - "example.com"
> - "*.example.com"
> - "example.test"
> - "localhost"
> - "127.0.0.1"
> - "::1"
>
> The certificate is at "./example.com+5.pem" and the key at "./example.com+5-key.pem" ✅
> ```

I had been testing a Flask application using `flask run --debug --cert=adhoc` to run it as https, and I had to click through Safari's warnings about an insecure site every time I loaded a page. As soon as I ran mkcert as described above, I was able to run

```
flask run --debug --cert=/Users/username/example.com+5.pem --key=/Users/username/example.com+5-key.pem
```

and my site loads as https with no warnings.