# Install SSL certificate for localhost on MacOSX m1 chip

Tags: ssl, keychain, apple-m1

I'm trying to some code using REST API in Wordpress locally, but get this error

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

My understanding is I need to add the SSL certificate to Keychain, but I can't. When I try to add it Keychain asks form my admin login, and then nothing happens.

I'm on an M1 Mac running 11.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix curl: (60) SSL certificate: Invalid certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964175/how-to-fix-curl-60-ssl-certificate-invalid-certificate-chain)

Comment: @Bram Thanks, that that will add a certificate for that specific URL, I need to add one for the localhost

Comment: Then your URL is `https://localhost` and the above mentioned question still applies. Have you tried opening your website on Safari and performing the steps in the question? Have you manually added your certificate to the keychain? Is the certificate in your Keychain?

Comment: Yes, as outlined in the question I have tired adding it to keychain, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73517777/1163560) about how to setup **https** for **localhost**.

> [image]
> [image]